# overriding equals and hashcode method, returning false

Tags: java, android, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I have wifi signals using ScanResult class, I am keeping all the signal in arraylist of object containing all the fields such as ssid, bssid, dbm etc.

I want to check if two wifi signal objects are equal or not, so I override my equal and hashcode method, but it is returning false in some case even though the fields are same. I double checked the fields.

Here is my equals and hashcode method in property class, please tell me if I am doing anything wrong..

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if(this == obj)
        return true;
    if((obj == null) || (obj.getClass() != this.getClass()))
        return false;

    property sig = (property) obj;

    if(sig != null) {
        if (sig.ssid != null && sig.type != null && sig.bssid != null) {
            if (sig.ssid.equals(ssid) && sig.dbm == dbm && sig.type.equals(type) && sig.bssid.equals(bssid)) {
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    final int prime = 31;
    if (ssid != null) {
        return ((ssid.hashCode() + type.hashCode() + dbm + bssid.hashCode() + freq) * prime);
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need to include the dbm? It seems likely that the dbm may vary from the same signal for different scans.

Comment: Please show a short but *complete* program demonstrating the problem. We can't really reproduce the problem with just what you've given.

Comment: yes, dbm would varies but I have saving data in local database and want to extract exact signal on search, that is why I added dbm

Comment: Also, your `equals` and `hashCode` methods are inconsistent at the moment - `hashCode` uses `freq` and `equals` doesn't, therefore equal objects can have different hash codes.

Comment: Finally, I think you've missed the point of the "multiplying by a prime number" part of the normal hash code recipe. You don't add all the constituent parts together and *then* multiply by 31... you add, multiply, add, multiply etc.

Comment: You should have written a unit test that would test your equals and hashcode. You need to provide the answers that are causing a bad fail.

Comment: Ok, let me try the suggestions in above comments looks valid points....Thanks guys

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
sig.dbm.equals(dbm)
```

instead of

```
sig.dbm == dbm
```

if dbm is not primitive.